# TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

Why am I getting this error? I'm trying to output an image as a nested list of RGB values. Python beginner btw.

```
def imgRGB(im):
        width, height = im.size

        #create matrix
        matrix = []
        for i in range(height):
            matrix.append([0, 0, 0] * width)

        #get the rgb values
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                r,g,b = im.getpixel((x,y))
                matrix[x][y][0] = r
                matrix[x][y][1] = g
                matrix[x][y][2] = b
        return matrix
```

Comment: Your `matrix` is two-dimensional. You're trying to do *three* lookups. That last lookup is thus trying to treat an integer as if it were a list.

Comment: ...that is to say, `[0,0,0]*2` results in `[0,0,0,0,0,0]`, not `[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]`.

Comment: ...there's nothing wrong with that -- flatter data structures are often better than nested ones -- but your lookup and modification code needs to be aware of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0,0,0] * width` is a list with `3*width` integers, not a list of 3-element lists.

You want

```
matrix.append([[0,0,0] for _ in range(width)])
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm getting: IndexError: list index out of range
Why?

Comment: `x` iterates over the height, not the width.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because you're trying to do three layers of lookups into a structure that's only two layers deep.

To keep your structure two layers deep and fix your code might look like:

```
def imgRGB(im):
        width, height = im.size

        #create matrix
        matrix = []
        for i in range(height):
            matrix.append([0, 0, 0] * width)

        #get the rgb values
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                r,g,b = im.getpixel((x,y))
                matrix[x][y*3+0] = r
                matrix[x][y*3+1] = g
                matrix[x][y*3+2] = b
        return matrix
```

BTW, personally, I would use a *one-dimensional* numpy array as your `matrix` rather than any kind of Python list at all, and access with something like `matrix[(y*height) + x + subpixel_offset]`, where `subpixel_offset` is 0/1/2 for r/g/b. Or, depending on your access patterns, you might put the r/g/b offset at a different place and multiply (x*y) by it.

Either way, there's a lot less memory allocation and garbage collection needed, and doing accesses require nothing but (extremely fast) pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you. I want to output it (modified) with PIL(low) later, so I used this method... I'll try to get it working this way. Optimization comes later:)